# Redirect from domain to other one

Tags: 301-redirect, pagerank

I deal with the following problem. I am customer of one domain reseller, which has fair prices, fine administration, and I have all my domains registered by it. Recently I've created a new webpage using a free web service (those sites where you can create a simple webpages with some template after few clicks). This new web page has default address in the following form: "pagename.provider.cz", but I want to use my own domain "pagename.cz". And that is the problem, because the provider would assign domain name to my presentation only if I registered mentioned domain by him. That wouldn't be a problem, but he is three times more expensive then my favorite one.

So I am thinking about registering domain "pagename.cz" under my favorite registrator and then making 301 PHP redirect from it to "pagename.provider.cz". Shall this affect (negatively) my domain ranking? Are there any catches which I shoud care about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using free hosting can cause big problems for SEO.

1. Many free hosting sites get overrun with spam.  Google ends up penalizing sites under their domain name or sites that are hosted on their server.  Just having your site running as a subdomain of `provider.cz` is a big SEO risk.
2. Free hosting doesn't last forever.   I ran into this problem when I first became a webmaster.  I used a free host that eventually stopped offering free hosting.  I no longer had access to my site on their domain name, even to put a redirect in place.   What happens when you no longer have any control over `pagename.provider.cz`?

I would suggest that any webmaster should find *cheap* hosting rather than relying of *free* hosting.  The cost of hosting a website can be as little as $50 per year.

- You are already paying $10 per year for your domain name
- You are likely paying $300 to $1000 per year just for your internet connections for your home and phone.  Hosting costs for a website are minuscule compared to the costs of consuming content online.